# `git log --all --full-history --find-renames --follow <path>` doesn't go back to file creation

Tags: git

I'm looking at the source code of [this project](https://github.com/AugurProject/augur/).

I want to see the full log of changes made to `packages/augur-core/src/contracts/Augur.sol`.

I run:

```
git log --all --full-history --find-renames --follow packages/augur-core/src/contracts/Augur.sol
```

The log output eventually ends at commit [`45cc71f9237886540d584cdf34bd0a66a643dc08`](https://github.com/AugurProject/augur/commit/45cc71f9237886540d584cdf34bd0a66a643dc08) (from 2018), but from Github's diff, it's clear that `packages/augur-core/source/contracts/Augur.sol` was not added in this commit (although git-log did follow a rename to get to this commit). In fact, you can check that on the [blame](https://github.com/AugurProject/augur/blame/dev/packages/augur-core/src/contracts/Augur.sol#L593) of the file, the closing brace on line 593 was added 4 years ago (2017). Why does git refuse to follow the commit history further?

For reference, I have this repo cloned and I'm at `ae17af2d65835cec2c16c94f0838ce7be5d6524c`, branch `dev`.

Edit: my `git log` output: https://pastebin.com/UnBJKVR3

Comment: *although git-log did follow a rename to get to this commit* - at this point, `git log` is no longer looking for `packages/augur-core/src/contracts/Augur.sol`. It is looking instead for whatever file name it thinks was later renamed to `packages/augur-core/src/contracts/Augur.sol`. Perhaps *that* file was created in this commit.

Comment: This is something of a defect in `git log --follow`: it only knows about one file name at a time. When following parts of some merge (especially when using `--full-history`) it is not aware that it should perhaps go back to the new name of the file when it goes to the *other* leg(s) of the merge.

Comment: @torek _that_ file from your first comment wasn't created in the commit where git-log ends, I tried to clarify this in my original post. No renaming happened in the commit where git-log ended, either.

Comment: That's not important. What's important is that when `git log` is walking commits, it linearizes history. Let's use a hypothetical example: we start looking for a file named Z (its final name). Z is renamed in commit 1234 from Y to Z. It's renamed in commit 5555 from X to Y. If Git hits 1234 first, in this walk, Git is now looking for a file named Y. If it hits 5555 next, Git is now looking for a file named X. If it now returns to 1234 (a merge) it's *still looking for X* when it goes down the next leg of the merge, where the file is still named Y. It's not looking for X or Z now!

Comment: Basically, the follow logic gets fooled by a name change. When it comes back to some place where it should be using one of the *other* names, it ... just isn't. So it fails to find the file, all the way back to the beginning of time, because it's looking for some *other* name now.

Comment: Without `--follow` things actually work better, sometimes. The blame code uses a different algorithm, too. Unless you're going to fix `--follow` (which would be welcome, but note that this won't be easy), you have to live with these limitations on Git's ability to track a file through the commit history (there is no *file* history, only commits).

Comment: @torek thanks for explaining that. Is there a better option for tracing a file's history then? Or is the best alternative to manually follow where `git log` fails?

Comment: Currently, manual methods are all we have, at least in those cases where the existing `--follow` code fails.